# How do I make borders in a contingency table built in R?

Tags: r

I have made a contingency table in R, shown below:

```
count <- table (dframe1$Contact, dframe1$Brokenbones)          # create the table

 count                                                          # check the table

      0   1
  0 235  61
  1  54  32

dimnames(count) = list(

c("No contact sport", "Contact sport"),   # adds row names
c("No broken ankle/leg ", "Broken ankle/leg"))# adds column names
count


                 No broken ankle/leg  Broken ankle/leg
No contact sport                  235               61
Contact sport                      54               32
```

I would like to add borders to it though, to define the 'cells.' Is that possible in R?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `gridExtra`, I think it is a good option to create smart table:

[image]

```
mm <- matrix(c(235,61,54,32),ncol=2,byrow=TRUE,
        dimnames = list(c("No contact sport", "Contact sport"), 
        c("No broken ankle/leg ", "Broken ankle/leg")))
library(gridExtra)
grid.table(mm)


library(gridExtra)
grid.table(mm)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the help. I really appreciate it, it looks alot better. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you can use something from "pander" or "knitr". (I'm assuming you're just referring to how the table is displayed in the console--otherwise, there are many other much better recommendations if you are trying to create publication-ready tables.)

Example:

#### Basic table in R

```
> table(state.division, state.region)
                    state.region
state.division       Northeast South North Central West
  New England                6     0             0    0
  Middle Atlantic            3     0             0    0
  South Atlantic             0     8             0    0
  East South Central         0     4             0    0
  West South Central         0     4             0    0
  East North Central         0     0             5    0
  West North Central         0     0             7    0
  Mountain                   0     0             0    8
  Pacific                    0     0             0    5
```

#### Markdown table via knitr:

```
> library(knitr)
> kable(table(state.division, state.region))
|id                  |  Northeast|  South|  North Central|  West|
|:-------------------|----------:|------:|--------------:|-----:|
|New England         |          6|      0|              0|     0|
|Middle Atlantic     |          3|      0|              0|     0|
|South Atlantic      |          0|      8|              0|     0|
|East South Central  |          0|      4|              0|     0|
|West South Central  |          0|      4|              0|     0|
|East North Central  |          0|      0|              5|     0|
|West North Central  |          0|      0|              7|     0|
|Mountain            |          0|      0|              0|     8|
|Pacific             |          0|      0|              0|     5|
```

#### With the ascii package:

```
> library(ascii)
> print(ascii(table(state.division, state.region)), type = "rest")

+--------------------+--------------------+------------------+-------+---------------+------+
|                                         | **state.region**                                |
+                                         +------------------+-------+---------------+------+
|                                         | Northeast        | South | North Central | West |
+====================+====================+==================+=======+===============+======+
| **state.division** | New England        | 6.00             | 0.00  | 0.00          | 0.00 |
+                    +--------------------+------------------+-------+---------------+------+
|                    | Middle Atlantic    | 3.00             | 0.00  | 0.00          | 0.00 |
+                    +--------------------+------------------+-------+---------------+------+
|                    | South Atlantic     | 0.00             | 8.00  | 0.00          | 0.00 |
+                    +--------------------+------------------+-------+---------------+------+
|                    | East South Central | 0.00             | 4.00  | 0.00          | 0.00 |
+                    +--------------------+------------------+-------+---------------+------+
|                    | West South Central | 0.00             | 4.00  | 0.00          | 0.00 |
+                    +--------------------+------------------+-------+---------------+------+
|                    | East North Central | 0.00             | 0.00  | 5.00          | 0.00 |
+                    +--------------------+------------------+-------+---------------+------+
|                    | West North Central | 0.00             | 0.00  | 7.00          | 0.00 |
+                    +--------------------+------------------+-------+---------------+------+
|                    | Mountain           | 0.00             | 0.00  | 0.00          | 8.00 |
+                    +--------------------+------------------+-------+---------------+------+
|                    | Pacific            | 0.00             | 0.00  | 0.00          | 5.00 |
+--------------------+--------------------+------------------+-------+---------------+------+
```

#### With the [pander package](http://rapporter.github.io/pander/#tables):

```
> library(pander)
> pandoc.table(table(state.division, state.region), style = "grid", split.tables = Inf)


+--------------------------+-------------+---------+-----------------+--------+
|          &nbsp;          |  Northeast  |  South  |  North Central  |  West  |
+==========================+=============+=========+=================+========+
|     **New England**      |      6      |    0    |        0        |   0    |
+--------------------------+-------------+---------+-----------------+--------+
|   **Middle Atlantic**    |      3      |    0    |        0        |   0    |
+--------------------------+-------------+---------+-----------------+--------+
|    **South Atlantic**    |      0      |    8    |        0        |   0    |
+--------------------------+-------------+---------+-----------------+--------+
|  **East South Central**  |      0      |    4    |        0        |   0    |
+--------------------------+-------------+---------+-----------------+--------+
|  **West South Central**  |      0      |    4    |        0        |   0    |
+--------------------------+-------------+---------+-----------------+--------+
|  **East North Central**  |      0      |    0    |        5        |   0    |
+--------------------------+-------------+---------+-----------------+--------+
|  **West North Central**  |      0      |    0    |        7        |   0    |
+--------------------------+-------------+---------+-----------------+--------+
|       **Mountain**       |      0      |    0    |        0        |   8    |
+--------------------------+-------------+---------+-----------------+--------+
|       **Pacific**        |      0      |    0    |        0        |   5    |
+--------------------------+-------------+---------+-----------------+--------+
```

Comment: Thank you. :) I have installed knirt, but I am not sure where to use the 'kable' command in my code so as to make it work?

Comment: Thank you for the help, it is very kind of you. :)

Comment: @daroczig, I didn't know about that version of the documentation. Thanks!

Comment: @daroczig Would there be a way to make the pander output "ascii-only", i.e. no markup at all such as &nbsp; & **?

Comment: @DominicComtois not at the moment, but please submit a [feature request on GH](https://github.com/Rapporter/pander/issues/new) and I will be happy to implement that option in a few days.

Answer (score -1):

Here is yet another possibility, with the stargazer package.  It's primary goal is to produce good-looking `lm()` tables, but you can do more.

```
require(stargazer)
star <- stargazer(mytable, type = "text", 
                  title = "Stargazer with Summary = FALSE", 
                  summary = FALSE)
```

Comment: Did you try this with the sample data?